# gEth archive mode hosting AWS or Azure?

Tags: go-ethereum, aws, azure

Can you guys recommend a setup for running an archive node on either AWS or Azure? Is there any service that fits the needs for doing so the best?

Comment: Do not use Elastic Block Storage. Too slow. You need directly attached NVMe disks.

Comment: archival node will eat up a lot of space, the only cheap way to run archival nodes on HDD (magnetic storage) is to use `bcache` krenel module (previously patched to allow `writeback_percent` to 90% ) with a small SSD (like 500GB or 1TB)  in front of the HDD to cache most used device blocks, this way you will be able to process about 90K blocks (ethereum blocks) per day.

Comment: archival node is approaching 8TB , btw

Comment: 8TB aint that much tbh. I have a decent budget, just looking for the best experience and provider for it.